# Vectores R que contenga una columna

Tags: dataframe, rstudio, vectores

Hola soy nueva usando el lenguaje R, me piden un vector con nombre label que contenga la cuarta columna (Day) del *data frame* factor.
Me pide que cuando compruebe la class me de integer y no dataframe, pero no consigo hacerlo
gracias por la ayuda

label <- factor [4]

Comment: Bienvenida Li_9 a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Hola Li_9, la verdad no se entiende el enunciado, ¿un `data.frame` que se llama `factor`? suena raro, ¿un vector label? ¿no será un vector con nombre de elementos? no sé, si es una tarea, creo que deberías preguntar al profesor que es lo que está pidiendo.

Comment: si, perdona pregunte y lo cambie, con label se refería al nombre del vector

Answer (score 0):

Para escoger una columna de un dataframe simplemente basta con indicarlo.
Si tus datos son factor entonces sería
--> `factor[4]`

Si quisieras seleccionar de la primera a la 4 sería
-->`factor[1:4]`

`Class` solo indica la clase de dato por lo que no es necesario

Comment: vale y lo de vector label si me pudieses decir a que se refiere exactamente porque no encuentro info, muchisimas gracias

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres con label,ponerle nombre o como?

Answer (score 0):

Al final conseguí hacerlo, de la siguiente manera.

```
Label <- factor$day
```